# How to display future date and time with a math calculation?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, date, forms

I'm using Jsp. I would like to display a future date and time according to the current date and time.

Explanations. Customer purchases something on the site and on the `confirmation page` they see the date they ordered. I use     `<input class="input_ship" style="border:none; background:papayawhip; text-align:center;" name="OrderDate" value="<%= new java.util.Date()%>" readonly>` to display the current date to the user.

Now I would like the user to know when his order will be shipped by doing a simple math equation (`current date + X days later`) will return some date in the future. How would I go about doing this back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java you can do this following:

First of all you must convert input value to `Date`.

```
Date specifiedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse("YourInputValueHere"); //You can change your format pattern for your input.
```

For adding days to specified date we use `java.util.Calendar`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(specifiedDate);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 2); //This method added 2 days to specified date.If you want subtract day from specified date you can do this calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date value to a `Date`, something like:

```
 var currentdate = new Date(document.querySelector('input.input_ship').value);
```

Now you can set the date 5 days ahead using:

```
 currentdate.setDate(currentdate.getDate()+5)
```